# Is there a way to create a generated column in postgresql that will store a boolean value from comparing 2 dates?

Tags: postgresql, generated

I am trying to create a new generated column call memberstat which is a boolean that will hold just a 'True' or 'false' if the current date is greater than expiration date.

So far, whenever i create 'memberstat boolean generated always as (case when expiredate < current_date then '0' else '1' end) stored' this generates an ERROR:  generation expression is not immutable.

Is there a way around this? sorry I am not that familiar with postgresql

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen the function `CURRENT_DATE` cannot be used is a virtual column definition because it will change without the values in the row changing. A virtual column must be based only on the data in the same row.
The solution is to create a view using either your case statement or a simple comparison operator.

```
CREATE VIEW expired_or_not AS
SELECT 
  product_id,
  product_name,
  expiredate < current_date AS "expired" 
FROM table_name;
```

which will return `t` or `f`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `current_date()` is a function which does not accept any input parameter, and returns a date. Why do you say that it cannot be used as a function?

Comment: Because you can't use `current_date()` only `current_date`:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8295d7abd54de16f60f10a390a8b7f80

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the correction. Both work if mySQL / mariaDB but not in PostgreSQL nor Oracle.

Comment: `current_date` is how the SQL standard defines this, `current_date()` is not allowed according to the SQL standard.